# How to detect a collision in brick breaker java

Tags: java, collision, helper

This is my code but I need help with the edge cases. I need to figure out when the ball hits the paddle and then how do I make it turn around and go back to bricks?

```
public boolean intersectsWith (Paddle paddle) {

    //right edge
    if (x+radius <= paddle.getX() + paddle.getLength()) {

        setYSpeed(getYSpeed()*-1);
    }

    return true;

}
```

Comment: Please provide moreinformation. What is this about?

Comment: You should use java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D for your paddle and ball. Do so you can use intersects(Rectangle2D) to see if they collide. Another solution that I've used is using Areas and Area.intersect(...);

Comment: I have to make a brick breaker game and I dont know how to tell when the ball collides with the paddle. How do I do that?